# Sitecore preview not working

Tags: sitecore

I am having some troubles with Preview in Sitecore. I'm using version 6.6.

When I click the Preview button from the presentation tab, I see the following grey screen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwkft.jpg

When I click Preview from the Publish tab I get the following error in a popup.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZV0I.jpg

Here is my site in Web.config.

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/My Website" startItem="/home" language="en-GB" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

One thing I thought it could be is that the language is set to en-GB. Could this be part of the problem? All the items in sitecore are set to en-GB and I have updated the ClientLanguage and DefaultLanguage settings in my Web.config to en-GB as well.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Found the issue in a config file in my Include folder. I don't know why this is needed so I have deleted it. I don't know why it was breaking my preview either.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <encodeNameReplacements>
      <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-"/>
    </encodeNameReplacements>
    <sites>
      <site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="name">My Website</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="rootPath">/sitecore/content/My Website</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="startItem">/Home</patch:attribute>
      </site>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en-GB" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

Basically change **rootPath** to ***"/sitecore/content"*** if your website item is called **"home"**; if you have named your website item as **My Website** still change your rootPath to ***"/sitecore/content"*** but also update your **start item** to ***"/My Website"***

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that didn't work. I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: Hey.. Check out my structure here, might be useful: http://imgur.com/Od3oqfJ
I've tried rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home", rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/my website", rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/my website/home".
They all give the same error.

Comment: Do you these things configured properly in your web.config 
<sites>
        <website>
          <html>10MB</html>
          <registry>0</registry>
          <viewState>0</viewState>
          <xsl>5MB</xsl>
        </website>
      </sites>
And
<setting name="Preview.DefaultSite" value="website" />

Comment: Hi Shriroop, thanks for all your help. Please see the edit to my question. I have solved the issue by deleting an include file. I don't know where it came from. Sorry for messing you around.

Answer (score 1):

There are the following settings in the `Web.config`:

```
<!--  PAGE PREVIEW SITE NAME 
      Specifies the name of the site that is used to generate page previews, for example "website".
      If blank, Sitecore uses the value in the Preview.DefaultSite setting.
      Default value: "" (use the value of the Preview.DefaultSite setting)
 -->
<setting name="PagePreview.SiteName" value="" />
```

and

```
<!-- Preview.DefaultSite
     Specifies name of the default site for WebEdit preview mode
-->
<setting name="Preview.DefaultSite" value="website"/>
```

It means that Sitecore always tries to use the site called **website** for Preview by default.
However, your include config file changes the name of the site from **website**  to **My Website**. That's why Sitecore cannot find the **website** and threw an exception

> Site "website" not found

Answer (score 0):

do you have this item structure on your sitecore solution ?

/sitecore/content/My Website/home

It's strange you have under your rootPath,"Home" item like startItem.

Can you check please?

You also can look to this [document](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My structure is as follows (sorry it's not actually "My Website" but the site isn't live yet so rather not give that away.  http://imgur.com/Od3oqfJ
Even though I am not doing multi-site, I guess I have set up my structure so it will be easy to add more sites in the future.

Comment: I've tried setting a hostName in my site config too but it didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: You need to change in your case to:<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/my website" language="en-GB" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />

Comment: Hi, I have copied that exact site config and I'm still getting the same issues.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your home item please check with and try with both preview from Publish and Preview tabs: <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/my website" startItem="/home" language="en-GB" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />

Comment: Thanks for all your help sitecore climber. I found the issue, after your latest reply didn't make a difference and even if I put startItem="asdfasdfasdf", there was still no difference. I found an Include config file which add some site settings in it. I don't know where it came from or why it was added, but after deleting it the preview has started working. I will post the config file in my edited question, no idea why it broke my preview. Thanks again for helping me find the problem.